# Copy file with read only permissions

Tags: c#, file

I have this code:

```
try
{
   using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) { }
   File.Delete(pathToStore);
   File.Copy(path, pathToStore);
}
catch(Exception){}
```

I believe that the read and write attributes are set because I get the access denied error.
Is there a way to only set the read attribute in my code so i don't get the access denied error? My path is to a server and i have the permission to open the file and execute the file.

Comment: You are deleting the file before copying it?

Comment: Is the body of your `using` block really empty? If yes, why? And by the way, you are creating a file on the server (the `path` is on the server, right?) and you should have write access to the path.

Comment: Make that `catch(Exception ex)` and tell us about `ex`.

Comment: @AirTrickz gideon is onto something... by calling `File.Create` you risk overriding the original file - according to MSDN this happens IF the original file is NOT readonly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEWARE that IF `path` is not readonly it gets overwritten by your code according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) !

Since the block is empty I would just remove that `using` block...

change your code to

```
try
{
   if ( File.Exists (path) )
   {
      File.Delete(pathToStore);
      File.Copy(path, pathToStore);
   }
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{ 
// do something with the Exception! 
}
```

One point though: It is usually a BAD idea to just swallow all exceptions !

Comment: yeaaiii :) this works fine. Thanks for all the answears everyone! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
File.OpenRead(path);
```

is this what you need?